# spring web flow enable scopes

Tags: spring, scope, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

Spring web flow provides additional bean scopes like flow, conversation, flash etc. I can define flow scope beans in flow.xml using var or i can set values to new scoped variables. How i can define it in spring application context xml file. I tried to use this pattern:

`<bean id="abc" class="abc" scope="flow"/>`

I got error that no scope defined. I searched on google and found this thing
http://blog.springsource.org/2007/05/08/spring-web-flow-bean-scopes-and-jsf/

but don't know how to enable it in spring web flow 2.3

Answer (score 0):

try to define it in your application context:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="flow">
                <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.config.scope.FlowScope"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old thread, but this might be useful for somebody.

The WebFlow library has a class that can register the scopes for you:

```
<bean id="scopeRegistrar" class="org.springframework.webflow.scope.ScopeRegistrar" />
```

Just make sure to register this bean before declaring "flow" scoped beans.